# Dockerizing NestJS APP and MongoDB "failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect"

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, nestjs

I want dockerize my nestJS APP and MongoDB, but i receive this error : failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

Dockefile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: erpcore
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - erpdb
  erpdb:
    container_name: erpdb
    image: mongo
```

Databases.providers.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
        useFactory: async (): Promise<typeof mongoose> =>
            await mongoose.connect('mongodb://erpdb:27017/erp'),
    },
];
```

Thank you

Comment: you docker-compose is just spinning up an image. Do you have the erp db created in mongo already.

Comment: normaly the nestJS app create the erp db automaticly

Comment: @SamirAFALLAH, Make sure that both your nestJs application and MongoDB is configured to be in the same network in your docker-compose file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your app starts before MongoDB. Try adding depends_on: erpdb on your app service

Comment: yes added, but does not work

***
version: '3'
services:
  erpdb:
    container_name: erpdb
    image: mongo
  app:
    container_name: erpcore
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - erpdb
***

Comment: The MongooseModule added a retry option to handle this kind of situations. It seems you aren't using MongooseModule, but you can check the source code to see how it was implemented: [https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/mongoose-core.module.ts](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/mongoose-core.module.ts)